# While loop with min and max conditions Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, logic, conditional-statements

I would like to charge a car under the condition that in the end it is charged at least 75% and if prices are positive I would like it to continue charging, but not surpass the maximum of 100%. The list of prices are the prices for everytime I charge (or decide not to charge) the car.

So here is what I have so far:

```
maxF = 100
minF = 75
SoC = 55
i = 0
chargeRate = 10
price = [2,-2,3,4]

while SoC < minF:
   if price[i] > 0:
       SoC += chargeRate
       i += 1
   # if there is no time left (no prices available), I have to charge in order to reach 75%
   elif (minF - SoC)/chargeRate <= (len(price) - i):
       SoC += chargeRate
       i += 1
   else:
       i += 1
print(SoC)
```

In this piece of code the car charges prices 2 and 3, but not 4. I don't know how to include for the car to continue charging, after having passed the 75%.

I am greatful for any suggestions.

Many thanks,
Elena

Comment: your `while` loop will stop if `SoC < minF`, as you specified. what do you intend to do with the variable `prices`?

Comment: Not part of your question, but as you have `i += 1` in every possible condition of your `if` statement, you should simply have it once outside of the `if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you should try the following code:

```
 while SoC <= 100:
   if (i < len(price)) and (SoC < 75 or price[i] > 0):
       SoC += chargeRate
   else:
       break
   i+=1
 print(SoC)
```

This should work for you. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the line

`elif (minF - SoC)/chargeRate <= (len(price) - i):`

Comment: I get a "list index out of range" error from your code.

Comment: @Elena my bad. I've updated the answer and this should work.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I just added `while SoC + chargeRate <= 100` so it does not pass 100 by charging in that iteration.

Comment: Happy to help! Please accept the answer so the question can be closed.